# Scan beans containing annotation in method at context initialization

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I need to do a very simple task: when a particular bean of my Spring context is initializing, I need to scan the entire context for Spring beans having at least a method annotated with [`PreAuthorize`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29). For each method annotated with `PreAuthorize` I will scan the predicate for a particular Spring expression of my interest (defined as custom Spring Expression).

That expression will be used to construct a collection of permission object

Example

```
@Component
public class Foo{
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN') || hasMyCustomToken('ABCDE')")
    public void foo(){}
}

@Component
public class Bar{
    @PreAuthorize("hasMyCustomToken('FGHIJ')")
    public void bar(){}
}
```

I will then make a `Set<String> allTokensInMyCodebase = {"ABCDE","FGHIJ"}` after scanning all possible expression arguments in the context.

I know that I can obtain a list of [all beans with an annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29), but that only scans the class for the annotation. Instead I need to get all bean methods.

I also know that this is uncommon practice, because Spring Security (and Tx, for the @Transactional) intercept annotated methods at runtime with AOP, only when the method is called. After all, an authorization expression should be normally evaluated only at runtime and not at context startup.

**Maybe** I could try to scan the context against **every** bean and reflect on all methods.

Is there a smarter way? My boss talked about annotation processing, but I cannot find any documentation for Spring annotation processing at method level with the exception of AOP, which runs just in time and not ahead of time (`ahead` === context start)

Comment: What do you then need to do with the `allTokensInMyCodebase`?

Comment: You can intercept every bean on creation with a `BeanPostProcessor`, use reflection to get the bean object's class type, then scan that type's methods, then do your annotation parsing.

Comment: Have you looked at `org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils`? May be you could use some of the methods there not to write everything from scratch, specifically `findAnnotation`